# Permission error when trying to read a file using python

Tags: python, file-permissions

I am trying to read a file from using python, it gives me `'Permission Denied'` for some reason.

The user I am using has privileges to read the file, I tested using `CAT` command on the file name. It worked fine.

I am not able to read the same file from a python program.

[image]
This is a `solaris` server.

Comment: Please dump the output of "ls -lt alert_dsvc.log" and "whoami"

Comment: ls command output
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba      54636205 Apr 14 05:39 alert_dsvc.log
whoami did not work, so tried id
uid=935(user_svc) gid=101(est)